# Updating SQL server table with vb.net 2010 datagridview

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, dataset, sqldataadapter

I am having trouble updating my database table with datagridview, I've read some thread about the problem and nothing seem to work in my case. Here is the code i use when populating the datagridview.

```
    Public Sub filldatagridserver(ByRef SQL As String, ByRef dg As DataGridView)
    Dim myDataset As DataSet = New DataSet
    myAdptr.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(SQL, cnSQL)
    myAdptr.Fill(myDataset)

    dg.DataSource = myDataset.Tables(0)
    dg.AutoResizeColumns()

    myAdptr.Dispose()
    myDataset.Dispose()
    cnSQL.Close()

    End Sub
```

then i call this sub procedure with the ff code:

```
    Call filldatagridserver("SELECT * FROM tblQuarterCollection", dgQuarter)
```

i already used myAdptr.update but i keep getting error about table mapping etc. I also tried to quote out the dispose and close in that sub procedure but it still doesn't work.

is there anyway to properly populate the datagridview and update changes made to database. I think my last resort here would be looping thru each record the update the data according to current value in the datagridview. Please help.

Comment: It will be useful to see the code that calls the update, however if you destroy the adapter then you could not update anything with that

Comment: @steve this is what i use when doing the update.
myAdptr.Update(myDataset, "tblPayMTC")

Comment: Then add the name of the table also when you fill the dataset     myAdptr.Fill(myDataset, "tblPayMTC"). Another important point to get the automatica update working is to have a primary key returned by the SELECT query. Did you have a primary key defined for your table?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the Update passing also the name of the table then you need to add that name when you fill initially the DataSet

```
myAdptr.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(SQL, cnSQL)
myAdptr.Fill(myDataset, "tblPayMTC")
```

Another important point to get the automatic update working is to have a primary key returned by the SELECT query otherwise you need to write your own commands for the UpdateCommand, InsertCommand and DeleteCommand of the SqlDataAdapter instance.

The [primary key](http://databases.about.com/cs/administration/g/primarykey.htm) is a column in your table `tblQuarterCollection` that uniquely identifies your records (usually an ID column with Identity set to true) but it can be also a group of columns that taken togheter works as Primary Key.
While it is not mandatory to have a column with this property set, it is highly advisable to have one

Comment: thanks for the reply, do you have a sample code how to manually write the update/insert/delete command for the adapter?

Comment: No, it depends on your table INSERT INTO table (field list) VALUES (parameter list) the same for the UPDATE, but it should not be required if you have a primary key defined in the table (as it should be)

Comment: hi, sorry I was out for a while. I've set a primary key but i still get the error. "Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.".

IF i use the SQL update command what parameters should i set? the value of each cell in the datagridview? will it automatically increment for each rows?

Comment: I've read about commandbuilder so i used it in update button(Dim cb = New SqlCommandBuilder(myAdptr)). now I got a new error.

"Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information."

Comment: As I have said, your table should have a column designated as primary key and this column should be returned by the SELECT statement, otherwise it is not possible to update or delete anything from your table

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
Dim addcmd as new sqlcommand("INSERT INTO TableName VALUES(@col1,@col2)",YourConnectionString)
addcmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@col1",txtCol1.text)
addcmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@col2",txtCol2.text)
addcmd.executenonQuery


End Sub
```

Comment: hi @Unknownymous I can't quite figure out where to put your code

Answer (score 0):

At last I managed to get my code working. I reviewed my database and reset the primary key and now it is working perfectly fine